# SQL Query to order by alpha numeric values

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-order-by

What is the issue in below query?

I'm expecting output as 10, 10A, 10B in below screen. But something wrong in my query.

[image]

Here is my sqlfiddle link. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3bbfe/1

Answer (score 0):

In your **query** you are **sorting by 2 columns**. One is based on `@sortby` variable and another is `name` at the **second last line** of your query below. The issue is, when you are only picking the **integer part** of `Id` it is 10 for these three rows you have mentioned in your question above, then order by based on second column **[name]** applies, which is `A` for `10B` and `B` for `10A`. If you remove name column from your order by clause you will get correct result. Hope this will solve your problem.

```
declare @sortby varchar(100)
set @sortby = 'Id'
select * from emp

ORDER BY
   CASE @sortby
      WHEN 'Id' THEN
         CASE
            WHEN ISNUMERIC(Id)=1
               THEN CAST(Id as int)
            WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',Id) > 1
               THEN CAST(LEFT(Id,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',Id) - 1) as int)
            ELSE 2147483648
      END
   End,

   CASE @sortby
      WHEN 'Name' THEN
         Case 
            WHEN ISNUMERIC(Id)=1
               THEN NULL
            WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',Id) > 1
               THEN SUBSTRING(Id,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',Id) ,50)
            ELSE Id
      END
   End

,  Name

DROP TABLE Emp
```

Comment: Yes I understand that. But I want to have second column as well in my sort. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Your 2 requirements are just conflicting. :) if you will keep name in order by then it will show its behaviour correctly.